# I want to extract a sin function from a sting in python

Tags: python, function, trigonometry

I have a string like
"4+5+6+sin(30)"

I want 30 from this string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to capture all function parameters, you could try:

```
inp = "4+5+6+sin(30)"
params = re.findall(r'\b\w+\((.*?)\)', inp)
print(params)

['30']
```

This uses the regex pattern `\b\w+\((.*?)\)` to target all function calls, capturing only the parameter value itself.

Answer (score 0):

You could also you python's strip function as well, which would look like so.

```
a = '4+5+6+sin(30)'
print(a.strip('4+5+6+sin()'))
```